# Binding Vuex data to vue-meta

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-meta

I'm working on a blog and I'm having a hard time trying to plug Vuex and Vue-meta. Here is the code :

On the article template, I use a `v-for="article in selectedArticle"` and a computed property to display the correct article from Vuex

```
selectedArticle() {
   return this.$store.state.articles.filter(article => article.id == this.$route.params.id);
},
```

I'm trying to use Vue-meta in this way :

```
metaInfo: {
    title: ???, 
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { vmid: 'description', name: 'description', content: ???.id },
      {
        'property': 'og:image',
        'content': https://api.someurl.com/article/ + ???.id,
        'vmid': 'og:image'
      }
     ]
}
```

I think one way to do it would be to bind the vuex data retrieved in `SelectedArticle` to the actual `data` property of the component, and then use `title : this.article.title` in `metaInfo`. 
But I don't know how to do it and I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Any other suggestions?

Thank you very much

Comment: This a sample application that maps computer property values to vue-meta metaInfo properties. https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/tree/master/examples/vuex/views. You should be able to just do `content: this.selectedArticle.id` or `title: this.selectedArticle.title` for example. Try that and let us know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately it doesn't work : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: That linked example demonstrates the benefits of getters with default values for a given "detail" item to help prevent undefined errors. Do you have default values for `selectedArticle.title` and `selectedArticle.id`, even just empty strings? This also asks a bigger question of how you are planning to handle find() returning `undefined` for the computer property.